# New measures to prevent spam in comments of nodes?

Tags: media, captcha, advertising

I have a website with a node and comments which are moderated. I have installed [Cache module](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha), [Image captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) (light distorsion). There was no spam till a few months ago. I installed [Honeypot module](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot) and the few messages (probably automated) stopped being entered into the moderation list.

This week the site suffered a **massive** amount of flood spam. This coincides with the attack which is explained in Drupal.org. Is it possible that the attackers have learned how to override Honeypot and Image Captcha countermeasures?

How can I improve the security so the spam is reduced? My client will not allow more than a very small human input to delete a few spam messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this module will help you: [BOTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/botcha)

There are more protection methods than just honeypot.

Answer (score 0):

The [Anti Spam by CleanTalk](https://www.drupal.org/project/cleantalk) module might be another anti-spam module that could fit in your case. Some more details from its project page:

> Invisible antispam without CAPTCHA, questions, puzzles, counting animals, math and etc. Just install and forget.
>
> CleanTalk is a SaaS spam protection service for Web-sites.
>
> CleanTalk uses protection methods which are invisible for site visitors.
> Using CleanTalk eliminates needs in CAPTCHA, questions and answers, and other methods of protection, complicating the exchange of information on the site.

Optionally you may also want to look at the [Comment Trust](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_trust) module. Here are some details about it (from its project page):

> ... auto-approves comments by users with previously-approved comments. It rewards trusted commenters with immediate approvals, while requiring you to approve the comments by new visitors. Works for both anonymous and authenticated users.
>
> You can configure the threshold of approved comments an email address has to first achieve before gaining auto-approval. You can also provide a list of email addresses (or patterns of email addresses) to always exclude from auto-approval.